# Visual Studio C# Solution Structure Analyzer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am looking for something that can analyze the structure of a Visual Studio C# solution. The idea is inspired by the Solution Structure tool provided by the Feedback Center dialog of Resharper.

Unfortunately, that tool does not work for me - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-464803, so I am looking for alternatives.

Motivation:

I would like to send as much information about my solution to JetBrains as possible without disclosing the source code itself. This should include the solution and the project files, but with the mangled source code file names. For each file I cannot provide the source code, of course, but it would be nice to have some stats, like the number of methods and/or the number of lines of code and/or average lines per method, etc ...

Essentially, this is to allow a third party to estimate the size and complexity of the solution without disclosing the code itself.

Comment: why do you want to that

Comment: Added the motivation.

Comment: so what confused me is you mistyped word **Analyzer** to **Anonymizer**
'

Comment: Sorry for that. Fixed it.